# Solving a matrix equation problem

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I've been trying to solve this matrix equation but I just can't find the way to do it. The task is: Find matrix $\mathbf{X}$ from the equation in the photo where $\mathbf{A, B, C}$ are given matrices and $\mathbf{a}$ is a given number.

$$\mathbf{(AXB)^{-1}+aB^{-1}X^{-1}C=A^{-1}}$$

The problem is that I don't know how to manipulate with the equation in order to put $\mathbf{X}$ in one side side of the equation and the other matrices in the other side. If for example we have $\mathbf{AX=B}$ we multiply each side with $\mathbf{A^{-1}}$ on the left and we get $\mathbf{X=A^{-1}\cdot B}$

Can anyone help me!

Thank you!

Comment: Use the fact that $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$  
 Then the L.H.S. you have:  

$(AXB)^{-1} = B^{-1}(AX)^{-1} = B^{-1}X^{-1}A^{-1}\\$  

and so you have:  

$B^{-1}X^{-1}A^{-1}+aB^{-1}X^{-1}C=A^{-1}\\ $  

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: @thedilated    Not actually. If you could give me some more help I would appreciate it.

Comment: By left multiplying with the inverse of B we have  $B^{-1}X^{-1}A^{-1}+aB^{-1}X^{-1}C=A^{-1} \Rightarrow X^{-1}(A^{-1}+aC)= BA^{-1}$  Then all we left to do is to make $X$ the subject.